# How to keep Gazebo from tipping?

Tags: repair

What can I do to keep this Gazebo from tipping when wind comes? The sticks that come with it to dig into the ground is not strong enough to hold it in place.

[image]

Comment: I see 4 legs either screw them to some decking or if in dirt use rebar driven at an angle away from the structure and attach a cable from the rebar to the leg above the flange.

Comment: Yeah Ed , he's doing this in the ground. Much better if it were on a deck... Rebar's are the cheap quick and most effective way 

Comment: No offense but this looks like a hunk of junk.    The manufacturer will probably get sued once someone gets hurt or stabbed by this.   But they will be out of jurisdiction.   My guess is about 120 on Amazon or alibaba.    Anchoring this either involves welding or putting a big "hook over each of the bottom rails.   Good luck.

Comment: 4 guy lines to decent pegs from the 4 top corners... But agree with the other comment about the design...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the steel legs are hollow, you could possibly drive some 
steel rebar pieces vertically and get 4 people to help you set it down on the ground over the 4 exposed rebars.

Parts: 
4 pieces of 6 foot long rebar's ( Home Depot /Lowe's sells 6ft length rebars.

Tools: Mini Sledge hammer

To do:
Drive  4ea 6 ft rebar's into the ground 3-4ft deep

Theory:
If this gazebo is sitting over 4 rebar's which are driven 3-4 ft. in the ground, and exposed 2-3 ft out of the ground, there's no way the wind is going to "knock it over.." And only *you* will know the secret.